# How can I install hsqml with Windows 10

Tags: qt, haskell

When I install hsqml, I get the following error:

> ```
> cabal install hsqml
> Resolving dependencies...
> Configuring hsqml-0.3.4.1...
> Failed to install hsqml-0.3.4.1
> Build log ( C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\hsqml-0.3.4.1.log ):
> cabal: Entering directory 'C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-16012\hsqml-0.3.4.1'
> [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-16012\hsqml-0.3.4.1\dist\setup\setup.hs, C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-16012\hsqml-0.3.4.1\dist\setup\Main.o )
> Linking C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-16012\hsqml-0.3.4.1\dist\setup\setup.exe ...
> Configuring hsqml-0.3.4.1...
> setup.exe: Missing dependencies on foreign libraries:
> * Missing C libraries: Qt5Core, Qt5Gui, Qt5Widgets, Qt5Qml, Qt5Quick
> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system packages that
> provide these libraries (you may need the "-dev" versions). If the libraries
> are already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the
> flags --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where they are.
> cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\wjsgm\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-16012\hsqml-0.3.4.1'
> cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
> hsqml-0.3.4.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
> ExitFailure 1
> ```

Comment: I am unaware about how that works on Windows, but you need to install the development kit for QT -- just having the libraries is enough for running programs, but not enough for developing new ones.

Comment: I installed QT 5.7 and set environment variable. But, i can't build this library